# Copy Paste issues in the designer

Tags: ssis

I have SSAS Designer version 9.00.4035.00

I am having real problems w/ copy paste operations. When i paste a task in, all the sequence containers get blown up really large.

Its not the end of the world, but it takes a simple thing and adds a lot of extra resizing to the process. 
Anyone have any thoughts?

Thanks

Greg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SSIS designer tools do a crappy job of handling the visual layout part of copy/paste, and I haven't found any way to make them behave. OTOH, once the layout gets screwed up, I've found the `Format | Autosize` and `Format | Autolayout` menus in Visual Studio to be the most effective way of getting SSIS packages to look decent.

Comment: ok, i figured the answer was deal with it. :-). Never hurts to ask, except in cases where forgiveness beats permission....

thanks for your time.